# Transaction revoked but ETH went missing

Tags: etherscan

A transaction I tried to buy an NFT was revoked but the ETH (0.5) is not returned to my wallet. Here's the hash:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x04be223665c985cd4e9f3e5397c39f760097a777cbc479369941003398b681bb

What could be happening here and how do I trace it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive it was refunded.

The reverted transaction is at block 13512477.

Sender balance at block 13512476 is : 0.676569869880535494 ETH

Sender balance at block 13512477 is : 0.666201248076312187 ETH

(I checked balance at block with [this tool](https://etherscan.io/balancecheck-tool))

That's a difference of : -0.0103686218 ETH, consistent with the fee paid of 0.010368621804223307 ETH.

Balance at block >13512477 would be 0.5 ETH lower if it was not refunded.

Comment: You are right - thanks and that tool is very useful